# Prove that if $\{ f_n\}$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $(0,1)$, then $\{ f_n \}$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\{ f_n \}$ be sequence of differentiable functions on the open interval $(0,1)$ such that for any $x \in (0,1)$ and any positive integers $n$

$$|f'_n(x)| \le 1.$$
Prove that if $\{ f_n\}$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $(0,1)$, then $\{ f_n \}$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $(0,1)$.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What about this?  –  [Prove that if $f_n$ converges pointwise and $|f_n'| < M$, then $f_n$ converges uniformly](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1716727/42969)

Comment: @MartinR: the answers to that question seem to use essentially that the interval is closed, which is not the case here.

Comment: @MartinArgerami:  That's why I left a comment and did not vote as a duplicate. But the functions are Lipschitz continuous (and consequently, uniformly continuous) and therefore can be extended continuously to the closed interval $[0, 1]$, therefore I *assume* that those methods can be used here as well.

Comment: @MartinR I will stop on the non-compactness of $(0,1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone already mentioned in the comment that the easiest way to do this is to first observe that each $f_n$ is Lipschitz continuous and hence can be extended to the closed interval $[0, 1].$ The proof of this fact, if you are not aware of it, provided in the previous answer.

I will provide an alternate proof below that avoids a little bit of this machinery (although morally I think there is not much of a difference in the two approaches).

Let us get back to basic and see what we have. Given $\epsilon>0,$ and $x\in (0, 1)$ we can find $N_x$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N_x.$ This is the definition of pointwise convergence. To prove that convergence is uniform, we need to choose $N$ that works for all $x.$ As you might imagine, if we had finitely many $N_x,$ we can choose $N$ to be the maximum of them. To get only finitely many $N_x,$ we need to show something like $N_x$ works not only for $x,$ but it also works for $y$ in a small neighborhood of $x.$ To do this, we let us fix $y$ close to $x$ (we'll see how close in a moment) and see what we can say about $|f_n(y)-f(y)|.$ Obviously, one is going to use triangle inequality
$$|f_n(y)-f(y)|\le|f_n(y)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(y)-f(x)|.$$

This looks good. We already know that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ if $n\ge N_x.$ From the condition that $|f_n'(x)|\le 1,$ it is not hard to conlude that $|f_n(y)-f_n(x)|\le |x-y|$ for all $n.$ The last term does not depend upon $n$ at all, but it is about another animal $f,$ and right now we do not know much about it. So, the first thing to do is to figure out if $|f(y)-f(x)|$ can be controlled if $x, y$ are close. This is again not hard to see from the pointwise convergence that $|x-y|\ge|f_n(y)-f_n(x)|\to |f(y)-f(x)|$. Once we have all these pieces in place, the argument is pretty straightforawrd. And, now I will write it in a linear fashion.

Fix $\epsilon>0.$ For each $x\in (0, 1),$ there exists $N_x$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \epsilon/3.$ If $|y-x|\ge\epsilon/3,$ then $|f_n(y)-f(y)|\le \epsilon$ for all $n\ge N_x.$

Choose finitely many $x_i\in (0, 1)$ such that $B(\epsilon/3, x_i)$ cover $(0, 1).$ This can be done explicitly. If you want start with $0<x_0<\epsilon.$ Once $x_0, \ldots, x_n$ are chosen, take $x_{n+1}$ such that $2\epsilon/3>x_{n+1}-x_n\ge \epsilon/3.$ Since $x_{i}-x_{i-1}\ge \epsilon/3,$ it follows that $\le 3/\epsilon$ many balls suffice to cover $(0, 1).$

Now choose $N\ge \max_{i}N_{x_i}.$ To see that this $N$ works--take $x\in (0, 1).$ Then there exists $i$ such that $x\in B(\epsilon/3, x_i).$ Now,
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le |f_n(x)-f_n(x_i)|+|f_n(x_i)-f(x_i)|+|f(x_i)-f(x)|\le \epsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

By the MVT, each $f_n$ is 1-Lipschitz on $(0,1).$ Therefore

(i)... $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f_n(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 1^-} f_n(x)$ exist, so each $f_n$ can be extended to a continuous function on the domain $[0,1].$

(ii)... And the extension is also $1$-Lipschitz. So we can apply the methods in the link in a comment to the Q by @MartinR.

Proofs:

(i)... By contradiction, suppose $g:(0,1)\to\Bbb R$ is $1$-Lipschitz but $\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x)$ does not exist. Then there exists $r\in (0,1)$ such that for any $y\in (0,1)$ there exist $x'$ and $x''$ in $(0,y)$ with $|g(x')-g(x'')|>r.$ But if $y=r/2,$ this implies $|g(x')-g(x'')|>r>2|x'-x''|,$ contrary to $g$ being $1$-Lipschitz...  Similarly for $\lim_{x\to 1^-} f_n(x),$

(ii)... The continuous extension of $f_n$ to $[0,1]$ is $1$-Lipschitz because if $0\le x<y\le 1$ then   any $x',y'$ in $(x,y)$ belong to $(0,1)$ so $|f_n(x')-f_n(y')|\le |x'-y'|$ so $$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|=\lim_{x'\to x^+\land y'\to y^-}|f_n(x')-f_n(y')|\le \lim_{x'\to x^+\land y'\to y^-} |x'-y'|=|x-y|.$$